# User to role gets created but when refreshing web page the web site crashes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem which I don;t know how to resolve.  Whats happening is that when the user (Admin) assigns a user to a role and saves it closes the page and redirects to the `index.aspx` page.  All of this works great and when assigning another user to a role the previous user/role is displayed in my gridview.  However when refreshing the web page I get the following:

`The page that you're looking for used information that you entered. 
Returning to that page might cause any action you took to be repeated. Do 
you want to continue?`

And when clicking on continue:

```
System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: 'The user 'qwerty' is 
already in role 'Client'.'
```

This is my code I have: C#

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DisplayRolesInGrid();
            BindList();
            DisplayUserRolesInGrid();
        }
    }

private void DisplayUserRolesInGrid()
    {
        using (CustomMembershipEntities dataContext = new CustomMembershipEntities())
        {
            dataContext.Connection.Open();
            var UserRole = (from u in dataContext.aspnet_Users.Include("aspnet_Roles")
                            from r in u.aspnet_Roles
                            where r != null
                            select new { User = u, Role = r }).ToList();
            grdUserRoles.DataSource = UserRole.ToArray();
            grdUserRoles.DataBind();
        }
    }
    private void BindList()
    {
        foreach (var role in Roles.GetAllRoles())
        {
            ddlRole.Items.Add(new ListItem(role, role));
        }
        foreach (MembershipUser user in Membership.GetAllUsers())
        {
            ddlUser.Items.Add(new ListItem(user.UserName, user.UserName));
        }
    }
    protected void btnRoleAssign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string roleName = ddlRole.SelectedItem.Text;
        string userName = ddlUser.SelectedItem.Text;
        if (!User.IsInRole(roleName))
        {
            Roles.AddUserToRole(userName, roleName);
            DisplayUserRolesInGrid();
        }

    }
}
```

}

And then in `aspx`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="AssignModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="AssignModalLabel">Assign User Role</h5>
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <br />
                <p>
                    Select Role:
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRole" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvRole" runat="server"
                        ControlToValidate="ddlRole" Display="Dynamic"
                        ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    Select User:
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUser" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvUser" runat="server"
                        ControlToValidate="ddlUser" Display="Dynamic"
                        ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </p>
                <br /><br />
                <asp:GridView ID="grdUserRoles" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="Grid">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%# Eval("User.UserName")%>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%# Eval("Role.RoleName")%>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <br /><br />
                <div class="modal-title">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnRoleAssign" runat="server" Text="Assign Role" OnClick="btnRoleAssign_Click" />
                </div>

                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have no idea on how to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You get the message from your browser, as refreshing the page after assigning a role would cause re-executing that action (assigning a role) again, which probably is not what you want.

Using a [Redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirect?view=netframework-4.8) you should be able to bypass that behavior, as simplified speaking the last action `assigning the role` is replaced with `showing your aspx file`.

```
protected void btnRoleAssign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    // ...
    Response.Redirect("YourAspxFile.aspx");
}
```